Landsat Image Classification using Arcgis Pro, less accuracy and mixup in landcover
I am working with Landsat 8 image for landcover classification, like built-up, bare land, water, vegetation,etc. My study area is a city of Saudi Arabia.
But when I classify using ArcGIS Pro, taking samples for each class in detail, and even after using best practices for taking samples, There is mixup in response. Some of mountain area is also added in built-up.
If i make separate class of mountain, then mountain area show up in some built-up and urban area.
how to deal with this mixup of land cover? and get accurate classification?
I want accurate classification of a city, there are 4 classes, there can be 5 or more, but i want accuracy with landsat 8 image. There should not be mix up of land cover

I do not think your question is about programming. ArcGIS use is not on-topic on this site. We have sister sites about GIS and opendata (see links on top right icon), but also on the other sites, we do not understand what did you try. You should give example of what you tried and why you do not get the results you want: much easier to answer than a generic question.
